# Why is my 16GB SD card not being read in my Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, external-sd

Why is my 16GB SD card not being read in my Samsung Galaxy S?

I've tried to format it several times but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you installed Total Commander? If so it might tell you something about the mount point.

Comment: Have you checked the filesystem format on the sd-card? The Galaxy S only supports fat32 formatted sd-cards. It might help to insert the card into a PC and format it manually to fat32

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading:

[xda developers >. [Help] Changing Around Mountpoints for sdcard and extSdCard?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1786014)

> **Excerpt:** *Some previous Samsung devices had no external storage at all but still mapped the biggest flash partition to /mnt/sdcard.
>   The Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 has a Micro SD card slot on it (one of the reasons I bought the thing!), but I guess for compatibility they still mount an internal flash storage partition to /sdcard. The actual micro SD card gets mounted to freaking /mnt/extSdCard.*

---

First you need to find out **where** it is being mounted (on Galaxy S), and whether the command you are using is for **internal** flash OR the **microSD** card ..

Comment: Answer with only link isn't considered helpful. If the link doesn't work in future this answer will be useless.